# How to match a enum value with some enum values using linq

Tags: linq

I want to know what could be the shortest linq query instead of following if statement.

```
public enum ErrorMessage { Error1=1, Error2=2, Error3=3, Error4=4 }
ErrorMessage error = ErrorMessage.Error4;

if (error == ErrorMessage.Error1 || error == ErrorMessage.Error2)
{ 
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq will make this code complicated, 
code you provide is readable, fast and maintainable more than Linq will be

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
if (new [] {ErrorMessage.Error1, ErrorMessage.Error2}.Contains(error))
{ 
    //do something 
}
```

or

```
var bad_errors = new [] {ErrorMessage.Error1, ErrorMessage.Error2};

if (bad_errors.Contains(error))
{ 
    //do something 
}
```

if a single call to an extension [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) is LINQ enough for you.

I guess to most C# developers such a pattern seems strange (and it totally is), but if you're already working on a dynamically created list of errors you want to check against...

Otherwise, stick with `if.`

---

It actually works nicer in languages with less boilerplate, e.g. Python, where this pattern is commonly used and looks a lot nicer:

```
if error in (Error1, Error2):
    # do something
```

Comment: You could actually perform a cleaned up statement in C# with a custom extension method like `error.In(ErrorMessage.Error1, ErrorMessage.Error2)` although i wont really recommend it for multiple reasons.